# iPhone home button no longer works

Tags: iphone, hardware

Recently I dropped my iPhone, breaking the screen, so I had that replaced with a new screen by myself that I brought from Amazon.

Now that I replaced it, the iPhone home button doesn't work at all because when I press it, it doesn't do anything, no matter how hard or many times I press it, it still won't do anything.

Later on, I took apart the iPhone and replaced the home button with a new one, and this didn't solve the issue and yet I don't know why it doesn't work at all.

I have pictures of my iPhone 3GS, hopefully it should help or whatsoever.

How can I get the home button working again?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Which is how I found your question. I even replaced the bottom connector board and it still did not help. I guess the two small pins below the button have to hit the two pads on the buttom board. Where it says J3. But I tried shorting the J3 pads on my phone and that did not do anything.

Comment: I replaced a screen that was actually for the 3G instead of 3GS and had this same issue. You may want to double check the new screen.

Comment: Nope, I got an iPhone 3GS model screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that when you re assembled the phone you lined up the positioning of the dock connector correctly, a tiny bit off and it will cause the home button to not work.

See this [solution for removing the back of an iPhone 3GS](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPhone-3GS-Rear-Panel/1551/) for disassembly instructions. On step 29 you will see the importance of this components positioning.

Comment: But I didn't take off the back part, I just took off the screen and the frame, leaving the board with the phone back part as you can see in my screenshot that I haven't taken off the back part.

Comment: check connector 4, if you touch that slightly and kncok it, the home will not work.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure I didn't touch connector 4, I won't able to know if I touched it or not.

Comment: its really easy to, so i would move that around until you start to get a response, as that is the connection for the home input button.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't fix the Home button mechanically, you can use a workaround to still be able to use your device, provided you have upgraded to iOS 5 or later.

Enable "Assistive Touch": Settings -> General -> Accessibility. It essentially shows a home button on the screen. A good way to breathe life into a broken phone.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit of a long shot given the distinct possibility of this being a hardware rather than a software issues (because of historical circumstances). Having said that, I did have this same problem with my iPad 2 (was convinced that there was an issue with the hardware) and this was rectified by a ['hard device reset'](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430).

Have you tried this yet?